# Is it possible to execute swap with web3.js and forked HardHat?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, hardhat, uniswap

I am new at ethereum development and I am working on a simple script to execute swaps using web3.js.

My web3 is connecting to the HardHat forked server.

First off all I am setting up the contract for uniswap v2Router02 router

```
const uniSwapv2Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(uniswapV2Router02.result), "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D");
```

Then on demand I am running the following callback

```
   const handleSwap = async () => {
      const [currencyOne, currencyTwo] = pairName.split("/");

      const tokenFrom = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress("0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2"); // WETH
      const tokenTo = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress("0x6982508145454ce325ddbe47a25d4ec3d2311933"); // PEPE 

      const path = [tokenFrom, tokenTo];

      var data = uniSwapv2Contract.methods.swapExactETHForTokens(
          web3.utils.toHex(1000000000),
          path,
          account,
          web3.utils.toHex(Math.round(Date.now()/1000)+60*20),
      );

      var count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account);

      var rawTransaction = {
          from: account,
          to: web3.utils.toChecksumAddress("0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D"),
          data:data.encodeABI(),
          gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000', // Customizable by the user during MetaMask confirmation.
          // gas: '0x27101', // Customizable by the user during MetaMask confirmation.
          gas: web3.utils.toHex(9999999999999),
          gasLimit: '0x22000', // Customizable by the user during MetaMask confirmation.
          value: "0xDE0B6B3A7640000", // 1 full
          // nonce:web3.utils.toHex(100)
          nonce: web3.utils.toHex(count)
      };

      const signedTransaction  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTransaction, "XXXX my private key XXXX"); // private key

      const txHash = await web3.utils.sha3(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
      const transactionResult = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction).catch(error=>{
        console.log(error);
      });

    }
```

As the result I am receiving the following error in browser:

```
TransactionRevertInstructionError: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM
```

Hardhat is a litellbit more specifig and throws the follownig information:

```
Contract call: <UnrecognizedContract> 
From: 0xdd11751cdd3f6eff01b1f6151b640685bfa5db4a 
To: 0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d 
Value: 1 ETH 

Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
```

The simple transactions like transfers works as expected but the one that contains "Data" generated by `swapExactETHForTokens` does not work.

I check the contract hashes twice and download ABI from etherscan.

I have deposited part of the ETH to WETH.

I have started a fresh account and clean the history in MM where I am checking the results for transfers and swaps.

I have run the server in verbose mode, but still not much details.

I am planning write also a script in Python to double check problem

Answer (score 0):

Start by ensuring your token addresses, allowances, balances, and gas parameters are correct.

1. Verify Token Addresses: (`tokenFrom` and `tokenTo`) and double-check the addresses against the actual token contracts on the network you're interacting with.
2. Check Token Allowances: Have you approved sufficient token allowances for the `uniSwapv2Contract` to spend on your behalf? For example, if you're swapping ETH for PEPE, you need to approve the `uniSwapv2Contract` to spend the necessary amount of PEPE tokens from your account.
3. Check Token Balances: Ensure that you have enough tokens from (`tokenFrom`) to cover the amount you're trying to swap.
4. Check Gas Parameters: Are the gas price and limit you've in the `rawTransaction` object appropriate for the network you're using? Consider adjusting accordingly.
5. Monitor Transaction Errors: Instead of catching the error using `catch`, you can log the error and examine the details to get more insights into why the transaction is being reverted. Replace `console.log(error)` with `console.error(error)` to log the complete error stack trace.